# How to disable proguard for androidTest

Tags: android, android-proguard

How to disable proguard for espresso test.

I enabled proguard for debug build type. But i want to disable proguard for espresso debug tests.

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFile 'test-proguard-project.pro'
    }
```

and my test-proguard-project.pro looks like

```
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn
-dontobfuscate
```

Still proguard is optimizing the test app. Please help me how to disable proguard for test app.

Comment: Hi OP, did you manage to find a solution? It seems that testProguardFile is being ignored

Answer (score -3):

The way to do it is to turn on `minifyEnabled` but turn off `Proguard`:

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard false
```

Comment: This is not the answer as it disables proguard for the entire variant